# I used to mine Bitcoin back in 2015/2016 but can't find my wallet now

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet-recovery

It was on an old laptop that I got fixed. The laptop works but I don't remember my the app names of the wallet I used or the mining software. I tried searching for 'wallet.dat' and it didn't find anything.

I searched my email for key words like 'wallet' and 'bitcoin' and the only thing I could find is an old link that doesn't work anymore but re-directs me to Slush Pool. I tried to reset my password but it keeps telling me that my password is incorrect even though it successfully lets me change my password (and is able to send me a password recovery email). I don't remember my phrase, but I can go through all my phone pictures from 2015/2016 to see if maybe I screenshoted it. This is kind of my last resort as I checked and I have 4,000-5,000 pictures on my phone from those years.

Am I out of luck?

Comment: Can you give us anything else to go on? What operating system did the laptop run? Do you remember if you installed the bitcoin node software. Do you remember if you worked mostly through applications or through web pages? What level of technical knowledge did you have about bitcoin and computers generally? Were you likely to have compiled/built software yourself? Do you remember if you mined in a pool or solo mined?

Comment: Windows 10 Home
I don't remember if Bitcoin node software was installed or not
It was through an application, not web pages
I have a decent knowledge about computers generally and beginner about bitcoin
I didn't build the software myself, I most likely installed a prepackaged one
I mined in a pool

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry, forgot to tag you

Comment: If you mined in a pool, there are two possibilities: 1) You just left the bitcoin in your pool account and it was waiting for you to withdraw it and you need to get access to that pool account. 2) You setup automatic withdrawals to some wallet you had somewhere and need to get access to that wallet.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's definitely #1. Is there a way for me to access that pool account with the information I provided? If not, what else would I need to access that pool account?

Comment: If the pool is still around, email-based password recovery is your best bet.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks! I got in and found my BTC. Appreciate the help!